# Function is only executed halfway

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function in JS:

```
function test(value, requirement)
{
    console.log("value: '" + value + "' requirement: '" + requirement + "'");
    var regExp = new RegExp(requirement, '');
    console.log("regExp: " + regExp);
    var str = "" + value;
    console.log("str: " + str);// [1]
    var ok = str.test(regExp);// [2]
    console.log("ok: " + ok); // [3]
    return ok;
}
```

I execute it in Firefox with Firebug enabled and the console shows:

```
value: '123' requirement: '^123$'
regExp: /^123$/
str: 123
```

Until [1](http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Objekte/RegExp) everything works as expected. Why is [3] not executed? What's the problem with [2] and how do I fix it?

Edit: I used the code from [here](http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Objekte/RegExp) (sorry, it's german) and no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is a method of RegExp, not String:

```
regExp.test(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

`test()` is a method of the RegExp, not the string - you need this:

```
var ok = regExp.test(str); // [2]
```

(Also, you should always run your code with the JavaScript console open - that would show you an error message that would help you identify the problem.)

Comment: I had the console open and it showed no errors. Do I need to activate somehow?

Comment: That's odd.  You should see something like "Uncaught TypeError: str.test is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error

It should be

```
  regExp.test(str)
```

test is a method of regEx. type string does not have any method named "test"